# Error when paging in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with two columns. The first shows a date and the second, the year of the date in the first column. So far everything works well but when I change page, the web fails with the message: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

This is my code:

Test.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="qq_site_Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" 
            AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            EnableModelValidation="True" onrowcreated="GridView1_RowCreated" 
            onpageindexchanged="GridView1_PageIndexChanged" 
            onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="creationDate" HeaderText="creationDate" SortExpression="creationDate" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Year">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>                
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Test.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Data;

public partial class qq_site_Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    static DataSet ds;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            String connectionString = "DSN=kitchenmaster.es.qq-site;";
            String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblSystems WHERE ID < 100";

            ds = new DataSet();

            OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
            OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(sqlQuery, connection);
            OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(command);

            try
            {
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime dt = (DateTime)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "creationDate");
                e.Row.Cells[GetColumnByID("Year")].Text = dt.Year.ToString();
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);             
            }
        }
    }

    protected int GetColumnByID(String columnName)
    {
        foreach (DataControlField column in GridView1.Columns)
        {
            if (column.HeaderText == columnName)
                return GridView1.Columns.IndexOf(column);
        }

        return -1;
    }

    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }

    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.NewPageIndex != -1)
            {
                GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: What is the exact line of code where you receive the above exception ?

Comment: The exception occurs in the event GridView1_RowCreated()

Comment: which *line* and what is the exception?

Answer (score 1):

This line of code

```
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
```

is probably where you are getting the error.

When the `GridView1_PageIndexChanging` event is called, you have not yet set the value for `ds`. The only part in your code that does so is in the `Page_Load` event, and only when it's not a postback.

Answer (score 0):

If I check the value of the e.Row.DataItem in the event GridView1_RowCreated(), the error not occurs but I don't know if it's the right thing to do. The new version of the event is:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.Row.DataItem != null)
                {
                    DateTime dt = (DateTime)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "creationDate");
                    e.Row.Cells[GetColumnByID("Year")].Text = dt.Year.ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("** " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sure, you avoid the error, but does your pagination actually work?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your "ds" object inside in PageIndexChanging event.
First fill the data set and bind.